# Perform local standard deviation in Python

Tags: python, statistics, standard-deviation

I am trying to obtain the local standard deviation of each pixel of an image.This means that for each pixel I want to calculate the standard deviation of its value and its neighbors'. I used [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.statistics.html) library 
I developed the following code:

```
def stdd(image, N):
    width = image.shape[0]
    heigth = image.shape[1]
    desv = np.zeros((width,heigth))
    for i in range (width):
        for j in range (heigth):
            if i < N :
                mini = 0
            else :
                mini = i - N
            if (i+N) > width :
                maxi = width
            else : 
                maxi = N + i
            if j < N :
                minj = 0
            else :
                minj = j - N
            if (j+N) > heigth :
                maxj = heigth
            else : 
                maxj = N + j
            window = image[mini:maxi,minj:maxj]
            desv[i,j] = window.std()
    return desv
```

Where N is the size of the local matrix for each pixel and image is a numpy.array() image
The problem of my code is that it takes too much to process it, and I would like to know if there is an already defined function which optimizes it

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd start by looking here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html

Comment: @NPE I looked at it and the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.standard_deviation.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.standard_deviation) does not really help me with the problem I have. I want to perform a standard deviation for every pixel in the image, but I want to perform it locally, in each pixel's neighborhood

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to calculate the standard deviations all at once, using [the following identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition):
[image: Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2]

To get the sum of all elements in a local neighborhood, you can use a [convolution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html).

```
def std_convoluted(image, N):
    im = np.array(image, dtype=float)
    im2 = im**2
    ones = np.ones(im.shape)
    
    kernel = np.ones((2*N+1, 2*N+1))
    s = scipy.signal.convolve2d(im, kernel, mode="same")
    s2 = scipy.signal.convolve2d(im2, kernel, mode="same")
    ns = scipy.signal.convolve2d(ones, kernel, mode="same")
    
    return np.sqrt((s2 - s**2 / ns) / ns)
```

**Warning:** Please not that while the results look good on a few test images, this function not return the same results as your code, but I can't spot the error right now. (If someone sees it: would you be so kind to point it out or edit it?)

Anyway, the idea is still valid and runs a lot faster (about a factor of 10 on my computer).

Comment: I developed myself the same idea of convolute each pixel. However, the sqrt() was imposible to calculate because it has negative values. So it makes me think that the equation is not ok

Comment: the error is the dtype of the image. Using float type it did not work in my PC as well. However, using numpy.uint32 as de dtype of im will solve the problem. This is because when you operate the square of im, the result is much bigger than the max value accepted by a float type

Comment: @max Both expressions are the same. [Link to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=show+sqrt%28%28t+-+s**2+%2F+n%29+%2F+n%29+%3D+sqrt%28+t+%2F+n+-+%28s+%2F+n%29**2%29)

Comment: Hmm I would suggest to divide the `ones` array already by its size. Because then you immediately take the average

Answer (score 9):

You can try the following

```
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter
import numpy as np
generic_filter(img, np.std, size=3)
```

Comment: It feels like this should be the new accepted answer

Comment: Both answers give the same (except for edge effects), but `generic_filter` runs anywhere from 10-50x slower than the accepted answer, depending on the image/kernel sizes